# RFID system inductive coupling

Tags: rfid

At low or high frequencies the communication between RFID reader and RFID tag is through inductive coupling. Why do we need a transponder? Don't we need only a receiver?

And how is the message of the tag not confused with the RF signal of the reader?

Comment: Q1: Think: What powers the RFID card? Q2: That will be explained in most basic RFID tutorials.

Comment: a) The radio waves coming from the reader power the tag or the tag has its own power supply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**transponder**
/tranˈspɒndə,trɑːnˈspɒndə/
*noun*

a device for receiving a radio signal and automatically transmitting a different signal.
*Source: Definitions from Oxford Languages*

A transponder is required because it has to read the trigger / power signal and then send a response.

A search such as [rfid+how+it+works](https://www.google.com/search?q=rfid+how+it+works) will give you plenty of reading material.